# jQuery - Fading Different Elements In and Out On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, fadeout

I'm trying to create a few buttons that make a box appear depending on which button is clicked. I'm doing this by giving each box it's own class and passing an argument to a function to identify which box is meant to be targeted. I'm then assigning this function to each button's onclick attribute on the page (I know I should probably attach the event handler in a separate file). Here is the function:

```
var show = function(boxNumber){
    if($(this).hasClass('shown')){
       $(this).removeClass('shown');
       $(this).html('Show');
       $('.box'+boxNumber).fadeOut(1000);
      }
    else{
       $(this).html('Hide');
       $(this).addClass('shown');
       $('.box'+boxNumber).fadeIn(1000);
      }
 };
```

The html:

```
<span onclick="show(1)">Box 1</span>
<div class="box1"></div>

etc. for more boxes
```

This function doesn't work however. Firstly, the this keyword doesn't seem to be targeting the button because the html of the button doesn't change on click. However, when I replace the this keyword with the class of the button it works fine.

Secondly, the function fades the boxes in fine but then does not hide them if I click the button again.

I'm stuck so any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using the onClick attribute. If you use jQuery, you could use the on event handler. Add an ID on your span, then $('my-id').on('click', function() { ... $(this).fadeOut(1000);})

Comment: I made a for loop to add a click event to each button but it led to more problems. I had to add a unique class to each button and then loop through them. The loop looked like: for(i=0;i<5;i++){$('.button'+i).click(function(){/*add fade in and fade out code from above but use 'i' to identify the box instead of an argument*/})}. I'm not sure why but the loop didn't work :(

Comment: Your span doesn't have a class of `button#` on it. That's probably why your loop didn't work.

Comment: I added the class when I was using the loop but removed it once I tried using onclick.

Comment: @user2022646: `this` in the context of onclick is not what you think it is. You'll need to pass it to the function to get the clicked `<span/>` as `this`. For example: `<span onclick="show(1,this)"/>`. I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1 (all jQuery):

The cleanest way to do this is to stick with jQuery for the click handling. You're already using jQuery for the fades, why not utilize it for binding the clicks? Try this:

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fVENv/)

```
<span>Box 1</span>
<div class="box1"></div><br/>
<span>Box 2</span>
<div class="box2"></div><br/>
<span>Box 3</span>
```

```
$('span').click(function () {
    var boxNumber = $(this).index('span') + 1;
    if ($(this).hasClass('shown')) {
        $(this).removeClass('shown');
        $(this).html('Show');
        $('.box' + boxNumber).fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        $(this).html('Hide');
        $(this).addClass('shown');
        $('.box' + boxNumber).fadeOut(1000);
    }
});
```

**Note:** If you want the faded out boxes to retain their place in the document, try using [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) instead.

### Solution 2 (mixed):

However, if you do need to use the `onclick` attribute to bind the click handler as you've shown in your example, you can do it like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fVENv/2/)

```
<span onclick="show(1,this)">Box 1</span>
<div class="box1"></div><br/>
<span onclick="show(2,this)">Box 2</span>
<div class="box2"></div><br/>
<span onclick="show(3,this)">Box 3</span>
```

```
function show(boxNumber, elem) {
    $this = $(elem);

    if ($this.hasClass('shown')) {
        $this.removeClass('shown');
        $this.html('Show');
        $('.box' + boxNumber).fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        $this.html('Hide');
        $this.addClass('shown');
        $('.box' + boxNumber).fadeOut(1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: You could simplify that last function even more to just 2 lines, if you're not using the 'shown' class for anything other than switching on: function show(boxNumber, elem) {
    $(elem).html($('.box'+boxNumber).is(":visible") ? "Show" : "Hide");
    $('.box'+boxNumber).fadeToggle(1000);
}

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron. You're pure jQuery solution works great. However, I'm stupid and I forgot to mention that the boxes start off hidden with $('div').hide(); This seems to be causing issues because I need to click on the buttons twice at first for them to work. But when the boxes are visible from the start it works perfectly.

Comment: Then you had `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` correct. Just switch those back. I had assumed they were incorrect because I didn't know they were hidden to begin with! :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/fVENv/5/

The best way that I can see to do this is to add some hidden text with jquery on page load, and then toggle a class on click (as well as a fade toggle).

the html:

```
<p>Box 1</p>
<div></div><br/>
<p>Box 2</p>
<div></div><br/>
<p>Box 3</p>
<div></div><br/>
```

the jquery:

```
$('p').append('<span class="show">Show</span><span class="hide">Hide</span>');
$('div').hide();
$('p').click(function () {
    $('p').click(false);
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden').next('div').fadeToggle(function(){
    $('p').click(true);
    });
});
```

the css:

```
div {
    width:50px;
    height : 50px;
    background: red;
}
p {cursor:pointer;}
span { padding: 5px; margin-left:5px;}
p.hidden > .hide, p > .show  { display:inline }
p > .hide, p.hidden > .show { display: none; }
```